# Sample covariance matrix for each pixel (taking the neighboring pixel) and applying for entire image dimension

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, octave

The following is the code for sample covariance matrix for the single pixel. I have taken 10 neighboring pixels for the (1,1) including the first pixel of the stacked image. y_1, y_2, y_3 and y_4 are my four images. **Kindly do let me know if the question is not clear.**

```
y_cal=cat(3, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4);

Y_new=reshape(y_cal, [5586, 4]);

Y_new_cov=Y_new(1:10,:);

Y_new_cell = arrayfun(@(ri) Y_new_cov(ri, :)', 1:10, 'UniformOutput', 0);

Y_new_cell_tr= cellfun(@ctranspose, Y_new_cell , 'UniformOutput', 0);

Y_covariance_initial = cellfun(@mtimes, Y_new_cell,Y_new_cell_tr, 'UniformOutput', 0);

Y_covariance_final = Y_covariance_initial{1,1}+Y_covariance_initial{1,2}+Y_covariance_initial{1,3}+Y_covariance_initial{1,4}+Y_covariance_initial{1,5}+Y_covariance_initial{1,6}+Y_covariance_initial{1,7}+Y_covariance_initial{1,8}+Y_covariance_initial{1,9}+Y_covariance_initial{1,10};
```

Here 10 pixels were taken manually where covariance is implemented. I have the image dimension as 114 X 49. So the final covariance matrix generated is 114 X 49 x 4 X 4. How should I apply a square window to select the neighboring pixels for a target pixel and continue for other pixels also?

Kindly provide necessary assistance as it took me two months to write this code being from a non coding background. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way would be to use [`nlfilter`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/nlfilter.html).  For this function, you supply your function (the one to compute covariance), and it will apply it to a sliding window of your size.  For example:

```
octave> img = rand (64, 64);
octave> img_cov = nlfilter (img, [10 10], @(x) cov (x(:)));
```

Will call `cov (x(:))` for each sliding block of size `[10 10]` (after padding the original image with zeros), and return an array of size `[64 64]` (same as the input image) with those results.  Since you are using Octave, your window and image may have any number of dimensions.  So you can do this:

```
octave> img = rand (64, 64, 3, 4);
octave> img_cov = nlfilter (img, [10 10 3 4], @(x) cov (x(:)));
```

An alternative is to get all the sliding windows from your n dimensional image into a column (using [`im2col`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/im2col.html)), use a function that will work along each column, and then build an image back with [`col2im`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/col2im.html).  This may, or may not, be faster but does give you a bit more flexibility if you can warp your head around it:

```
octave> img = rand (64, 64);
octave> im_cols = im2col (img, [10 10], "sliding");
octave> im_cov = you_nd_cov_function (im_cols);
octave> img_cov = col2im (cov (im_cols), [1 1], [55 55], "sliding");
```

Comment: @Lalu I was quite explicit on my answer that it would work on Octave only. Matlab's `nlfilter` does not handle N dimensional input. If you are not using Octave, why did you use the `octave` tag on your question?